# How to create a loop that won't stop until the condition is satisfied

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and before learn C++ I have learned pascal. I have to keep repeat the input process until this condition is satisfied (`1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000`) in pascal it's pretty easy with the "repeat... until" command but in C++ there is only "while" which only stop when the condition is false

Comment: Use `while (! yourCondition)`

Comment: `do {...} while (condition)` would be the C++ equivalent to `repeat ... until`.

Comment: And take care to notice that in `while` and `until` the `condition` will have the opposite effect - determine whether to continue or to stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your conditions in a while loop separating each condition with &&  if you want both conditions to result true:

try this:

```
while(!(m>=1 && n>=1 && n<=1000000000 && (n-m) <=100000)){

    // your code here

    }
```

Comment: This will not exit the loop unless one or more of the stated variables within are altered before the closing brace.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true){

  if(m>=1 && n>=1 && n<=1000000000 && (n-m) <=100000)
     break;
  // do something

 }
```

Comment: I wouldn't  use `while(true)`. Its a bad habit, that caused me troubles lots of times.